# Codeblocks for C on Mac _ Running Issue

Tags: c, ide, codeblocks

I am a C learner and I'm using a Mac. I downloaded Xcode and Codeblocks as an IDE. I pasted a functional program's code into Codeblocks, built it, and then when running, I got the message below on the terminal (substituted my name for "username"). Could you please tell me how to fix this and get CB to work properly? Thanks.

```
Last login: Tue Mar 19 12:23:49 on ttys000
Username-MacBook-Pro:~ username$ /Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/username/Desktop/codeblocks folder/classproject/iob/bin/Debug/iob 
sh: /Users/username/Desktop/codeblocks: No such file or directory

Process returned 127 (0x7F)   execution time : 0.003 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my Mac, perhaps you need to create a project and save it somewhere first, because on windows you simply create a .c file but on Mac you need to create a project for every C program.

That, or perhaps you need to download the command line tools that you are prompted to download automatically with Xcode.